# What is the reason for daily time on site as high as '55.14' on Alexa siteinfo?

Tags: alexa

Alexa siteinfo of reservedeal.com display daily time on site as '55.14' whereas snapdeal.com daily time on site is '6.31'. I need to understand is there any SEO technique or code or data on site which is influencing the behavior of user which in turn impacting the data.

How should I interpret this data? Does it mean reservedeal.com site user so active on site that they stay so long or there is something wrong with data?

[image]

Comment: Alexa's data is known to be inaccurate. You shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: It seems like we say this at least once a week. Alexa is pure junk!! Ignore it! Please.

Comment: They often use the WAG method. Since they don't have anything on your website directly measuring access, how would they know? WAG = Wild (Donkey) Guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply a result of statistics and outliers.

The global rank of snapdeal is 171, whereas reservedeal is >123,000. If one user left their browser open on the page for a long time, it would make a much bigger impact on the average "time on site" on reservedeal than it would on snapdeal.

Also note that Alexa rankings are measured by people who have their browser extension installed, so they extrapolate data from several thousand people into visitor stats for billions of web pages. This makes their number inaccurate, especially for lower-ranked sites.